# unable to access the git repository in jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, repository

I am able to access the git repository through CLI.

But I am not able to access it through the Jenkins plugin.

I have updated the GitHub plugin, and I have updated the Jenkins version, but no use.

I have tried stopping the firewall and antivirus temporarily, but (again) no use.

Can anyone resolve the issue?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/buvnB.png]

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins agent might not run on the same machine, or with the same account, as the one used from CLI.

Follow "[How to Add GIT Credentials in Jenkins?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-git-credentials-in-jenkins/)", using the [Jenkins Credentials Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/).

[image: https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20220823114207/I.png]

Don't forget to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as a password.

You will then be able to specify that credential when entering the Git repository URL in your job configuration, as illustrated in "[How to Setup Git Repository and Credentials for Jenkins Jobs](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/10/jenkins-git-setup/)".

[image: https://static.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/jenkins-git-source-code-mgmt-tab.png]